# Using the Google text to speech service with spanish text

Tags: text-to-speech, urllib

I am trying to generate a voice message from text using the following URL:

```
"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=es&q=La+castaña+está+muy+buena"
```

With python, but the `urllib` library fails with:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 227, in retrieve
    url = unwrap(toBytes(url))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1051, in toBytes
    " contains non-ASCII characters")
UnicodeError: URL u'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=es&q=La+casta\xf1a+est\xe1+muy+buena' contains non-ASCII characters
```

How can I pass special characters (`ñ, á, é, í, ó, ú`), which have phonetical meaning, to the Google t2s service?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and found the solution [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541541/google-tts-api-encoding-get-request-with-php):
all I had to do was pass an additional parameter: `&ie=UTF-8`
That's it.

My resulting PHP looked something like:

```php
$q = "Años más, años menos";
$data = file_get_contents('http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=es&ie=UTF-8&q='.$q;
```

Note the `translate_tts?tl=es&ie=UTF-8&q='.$q` part of the GET parameters.